# Root finding in Mathematica

Tags: equation-solving

I am new to Mathematica. I have used the WolframAlpha online calculator to find roots of equations (listed under the heading `Root` in the output generated in response to a submission). When I try to find the roots of the same equation in Mathematica, I receive various errors. I have tried `FindRoot` and `Reduce`. Is there a function in Mathematica that corresponds to whatever is generating the `Root` output in the online WolframAlpha calculator? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE.  Please extend your question by adding some examples of the behavior your are seeing from both *Mathematica* and Wolfram|Alpha.

Comment: Maybe Roots is what he is looking for. He might also want to use ToRules on the result Roots returns.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The canonical way to solve algebraic equations is to use `Solve`,  e.g.

```
2 - 4 x - x^2 + 2 x^3 == 0 // Solve[#, x] &
```

> ```
> {{x -> 1/2}, {x -> -Sqrt[2]}, {x -> Sqrt[2]}}
> ```

The above  `eqn //Solve[#,x]&` is a so called postfix notation.

This is an infix notation:  `eqn ~ Solve ~ x`

and  prefix :    `Solve[ #, x]& @(eqn)`

If you want to solve a transcendental equation e.g. `x^2 == Cos[x]` you can use `Solve` as well as `Reduce`, however one should specify the real domain because by default `Mathematica` working in the complex domain cannot find all solutions.

```
Reduce[x^2 == Cos[x], x, Reals]
```

> ```
> x == Root[{-Cos[#1] + #1^2 &, -0.82413231230252242296}] ||
> x == Root[{-Cos[#1] + #1^2 &, 0.82413231230252242296}]
> ```

```
Solve[x^2 == Cos[x], x, Reals]
```

> ```
> {{x -> Root[{-Cos[#1] + #1^2 &, -0.82413231230252242296}]},
>  {x -> Root[{-Cos[#1] + #1^2 &, 0.82413231230252242296}]}}
> ```

If you are interested in numerical values of solutions you could also choose `FindRoot`, it works like this :

```
 FindRoot[ x^2 == Cos[x], {x, Pi/6}]
```

> ```
> {x -> 0.824132}
> ```

In general `x0`, here  `Pi/6` is the point where it starts to search a numerical solution.

`NSolve` also tackles equations numerically:

NSolve[x^2 == Cos[x], x, Reals]

> ```
> {{x -> -0.824132}, {x -> 0.824132}}
> ```

And here I briefly sketch a few samples of using  functions which you mentioned :

```
Roots[ 2 - 4 x - x^2 + 2 x^3 == 0, x]
```

> ```
> x == Sqrt[2] || x == -Sqrt[2] || x == 1/2
> ```

```
Root[ 2 - 4 x - x^2 + 2 x^3, #] & /@ Range[3]
```

> ```
> {-Sqrt[2], 1/2, Sqrt[2]}
> ```

```
Reduce[ 2 - 4 x - x^2 + 2 x^3== 0, x]
```

> ```
>  x == 1/2 || x == -Sqrt[2] || x == Sqrt[2]
> ```

Comment: Thank you to both of you (Artes, David). `Solve` resolved my issue, whereas neither `Root`, `Roots`, `FindRoots`, nor `Reduce` worked. I will have to read more on these functions to understand their different purposes.

Comment: Artes, could you please briefly tell me what the octothorpe and ampersand signify in your expression? After searching briefly, they seem to deal with "pure functions" and I read that `#` and `#n` refer to the first and nth variables, respectively. However, in your expression `#` appears to correspond more to `%` (output / result). The ampersand is supposed to designate that something is a pure function with variables that can be called using `#`. Thanks for your clarification.

Comment: `#` is `Slot` e.g. `#2&[a,b,c]` yields `b`, it represents an argument of a pure function, an `#n` represents n-th argument. `&` represents function, e.g.  (#^2 + # + 1)& is equvalent to `Function[w, W^2 + w +1]`.

Answer (score 4):

[`Solve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Solve.html) may be a good start:

```
Solve[a x^2 + b x + c == 0, x]
```

> ```
> {
>     {x -> (-b - Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c])/(2 a)},
>     {x -> (-b + Sqrt[b^2 - 4 a c])/(2 a)}
> }
> ```

Other functions that are often useful when solving equations are [`Reduce`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Reduce.html) (find a logical expression for all variables satisfying a statement) and [`Refine`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Refine.html) (add constraints on variables, such as being positive)

`FindRoot`, one of the functions you used, solves *numerically only*, iterating [Newton's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) until sufficiently accurate.

`Root` is, as far as I know, not really meant to find roots, it's much more an abstract representation of the $n$th root of an equation, much like $\sin(10)$ does make sense on its own, without evaluating it to an explcit number. In some cases for example, it may be impossible to calculate the root of an equation explicitly, so Mathematica keeps it as a `Root` object; however, once you apply numerical functions like `N` to it, it can still do some useful operations with it.

Comment: Thank you to both of you (Artes, David). `Solve` resolved my issue, whereas neither `Root`, `Roots`, `FindRoots`, nor `Reduce` worked. I will have to read more on these functions to understand their different purposes.